# How to Mock Date time for Magento 2

Tags: php, datetime, magento2

I have used behat many times in the past and today I've just got behat and selenium running headless chrome to make BDD acceptance features for custom development in Magento 2.  Previous methods have either been custom to the framework I'm using or have used [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and code looks like...

```
//Carbon
Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::create(2001, 5, 21, 12));  

//Silverstripe Framework
SS_Datetime::set_mock_now('2003-11-01 12:12:12')
```

...and having done this the entire application would then use this as the current date/time, including things like the ORM where it would update "created" times on database records.  I am now looking for the same thing within Magento CE 2.2.7 and have so far not found what I'm looking for.  There is [a dev doc page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/test/unit/writing_testable_code.html#the-environment-file-system-time-global-variables) that hints at this stating...

> Whenever your code requires access to some part of the environment, try to use a collaborator class that can easily be replaced by a test double (also referred to as a mock) instead.
>   For example, if you…
>   …need the current time?
>   Inject a \DateTimeInterface instance (for example [\DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.calendar.php)) and use that.

...however it doesn't seem to include any more information and after searching the code for this I'm still confused if there is a simple way to ensure the global system date-time is mocked or faked in this way so that I can...

1. Make an order on day 1
2. Move forward a day and process the order on day 2
3. Move forward a week and customer marks the order for return on day 9
4. etc.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you already checked out this post about Intergration Tests https://www.integer-net.com/integration-tests-with-magento-2/ ? Or does this not satisfy your question because the whole system needs to use a different date-time?

Comment: @kipzes thank you for your comment! Unfortunately I am not performing unit or integration tests where areas are instantiated and tested - these acceptance test with a headless chrome means the system is used in much more of a black box fashion and it's not possible to control every function call.  It is easy to call a piece of code or make the odd setting - but that is the exception of using selenium to remote control chrome.

Comment: The documentation you refer to wants you to use some form of Dependency Injection. That means anywhere in your code where the current time is required, a DateTime object or some custom DateTimeInterface should be injected. This way, in your integration test, you can change the dependency implementation to one that provides a fixed date. I don't see any other good way.

Comment: @JensV thank you for your comment.  As I say in the question I am performing acceptance tests with headless chrome, not integration tests where this level of control would be normal.  And to be clear I'm sure I could handle this in "my code" but this is more "magento core" code that I am asking about.  thank you again for your comment